# Getting whole text of an td in Python (lxml)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to get the whole text that is contained in this td:

Example:

```
<td>
 <p>Some Text</p>
 <a>SAMPLE</a>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    ....
   </tr>
   ...
  </tbody>
 </table>
 ...
</td>
```

There are lots of tags inside this td, which makes it hard for me. Even tables are contained.

In FirePath (Firefox) I can simply attach //text()

> .//*[@id='Testcases__list']/table/tbody/tr/td//text()

But in Python code the //text() part throws me an error, using the lxml library

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonscripts\Bachelor\TestMain.py", line 52, in <module>
    print tr.findall('./td[6]//text()')[0].text
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 1563, in lxml.etree._Element.findall (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:56897)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 304, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 277, in iterfind
    selector = _build_path_iterator(path, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 260, in _build_path_iterator
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](_next, token))
KeyError: '()'
```

How can I get the whole text of that td in Python?

Comment: why not just use `string(.//*[@id='Testcases__list']/table/tbody/tr/td)` - as per the [docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xpath/1903/finding-elements-containing-specific-text/6209/find-all-elements-with-certain-text#t=201610140847415913303), rather than iterate through each text node descendant?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using *.xpath* not *findall*:

```
tr.xpath("//*[@id='Testcases__list']/table/tbody/tr/td//text()")
```

To just get the first td:

```
 tr.xpath("(//*[@id='Testcases__list']/table/tbody/tr/td)[1]/text()")
```

I would also verify that the source actually has a *tbody* element, often it is added by the browser and not in the actual source.

You can *text_content*:

```
tr.xpath("(//*[@id='Testcases__list']/table/tbody/tr/td)[1]")[0].text_content()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here  I will Give you code.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import tostring,fromstring
import re

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')


tree = etree.HTML('''
<td>
 <p>Some Text</p>
 <a>SAMPLE</a>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    ....
   </tr>
   ...
  </tbody>
 </table>
 ...
</td>
''')
print TAG_RE.sub('',tostring(tree.xpath("//td")[0]))
```

Answer (score -2):

If it is a website, you want BeautifulSoup! https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("Your_Link")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.find('td').text
```

This scrapes the website looking for the td tag and will return anything between it. If this tag is a child of another tag, you need to look at parent and child tag relationships so that you can navigate to this particular tag and print its information.